# What is the word to describe someone whom you are gossiping about

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I was writing another question on [Workplace Interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32027/how-to-subtly-let-your-colleagues-know-that-gossiping-is-bad) when i realised that I did not know a term / word to describe someone whom you are gossiping about

What is a word / term to describe someone whom you are gossiping about ???

Comment: Your *victim*..

Comment: There are too many words to describe someone you are gossiping about -- an unlimited number. In fact, that's the whole point of gossiping: to describe someone (typically in unflattering terms).

Comment: _target_ is another possibility

Comment: @Drew He doesn't mean the words used in the gossip itself, but a word to describe the relationship between the gossip and the person.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I know. ;-)

Comment: How about *malignee*? Or "the *slandered*".

Answer (score 3):

**Victim**

You can be the *victim* of gossip as it is rarely complimentary, often malicious and entails judgement and criticism.

> Barry was a victim of gossip at work. It went beyond the usual
>   comment and speculation. His mates said Barry was on cocaine and
>   abused his own children. The heavy workplace atmosphere was getting to
>   him. What should he do?
>   <sup>[source](http://www.bmartin.cc/pubs/06whistle.html)</sup>

> Malicious workplace gossip is self-defeating, corrosive and belittles
>   both the speaker and the person who is the victim of the gossip. It
>   can be vicious way in which ambitious staff may see to undermine a
>   competitor. Or is may be idle gossips, lacking a motive, but still
>   being corrosive and damaging.
>   <sup>[source](http://janderson99.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Deal-with-Office-Gossip-and-Difficult-People-at-Work)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Subject** is the word I would use, in the general meaning of "that which is being talked about."  Works for gossip just as well as for other modes of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If *gossiper* is one who gossips, then you could always use *gossipee*.  While it's not very well attested searching the interwebs (though I did find it in at least one published book on pyschology), its meaning should be quite transparent to any native speaker of English most especially when contrasted with *gossiper*.

Answer (score -1):

Victim: The person whom one is gossipping about can be called as the victim.

A victim is a person who is the target of an unpleasant situation. While you gossip about someone, it is an unpleasant situation for that person. Hence you can call that person a victim of your gossip.